# Upside down mouse cursor and inverted mouse input

Tags: lubuntu, mouse, 21.10

I recently installed Lubuntu in my old Ghia OnlyDue+, everything works fine except for a fine detail: the mouse cursor is upside down and it's input is inverted in both X and Y axes.

I've tried a lot of stuff, regarding `xinput` and `xrandr`, but no solution. I algo tried removing the `iio-sensor-proxy`, but didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `iio-sensor-proxy` using:

```
sudo apt remove iio-sensor-proxy
```

After this you need to restart your PC. This work for me.